# Label Sync Perforce

Tags: python, perforce

I am looking for a solution that I can use to sync only label files to depot that will run automatically, I can be every hour or as things get labeled. I am not sure what I need to do this. I have a little Python and Javascript under my belt but I have not found anyone with this issue yet and need some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extremely simple solution as a Python script:

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

while True:
    system("p4 sync @LABEL")
    sleep(3600)
```

Practically speaking you probably don't want to use either Python or JS for this, since it requires that you always have that window up -- instead set it up as a background task via `cron`, the Windows task manager, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I understand there are better ways of doing this. Our dev team was working on a great solution but was pulled away on other projects and I need something I can run in a VM to hold us over.